# Inaccurate tracking with calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

I am trying to develop a program to track a license plate. I need to track plates and mark them with ID number so I can call my recognition program for every plate only once. I have a problem with tracking. Once I successfully detect license plate region I create mask to extract features only from plate and then track them on the whole image. I use `goodFeaturesToTrack()` and calculate optical flow with `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`. This is my algorithm:

1. Get a frame from camera.
2. Find license plate.
3. Extract features from license plate region.
4. Get next frame from camera.
5. Extract features from frame.
6. Call calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()
7. While we successfully track at least half of features from license plate we do tracking and swap features with next features.

Code(Only part):

```
bool licensePlate = false;

while(1)
{
    frame = cvQueryFrame(cap);
    if(frame.empty()) 
        break;

    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // We have license plate area
    if (licensePlate)
    {
        frame.copyTo(image_next);
        goodFeaturesToTrack(image_next, next_features, 50, 0.01, 0.1);
        calcOpticalFlowPyrLK( image_previous, image_next, features, next_features, features_found, err );
        swap(features, next_features);
    }

    // We try to obtain license plate area
    if (!licensePlate)
    {
        squares = findLicensePlate(image);
        if (!squares.empty())
        {
            // We have found license plate area
            licensePlate = true;
            frame.copyTo(image_previous);
            Mat roi (mask, Rect(bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height));
            roi.setTo(255);
            goodFeaturesToTrack(image_previous, features, 50, 0.01, 0.1, mask);
            mask.setTo(0);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is:

[image]

Green points are previous features and red points are actual features.

As you can see, the are somehow tracked good but it looks like they are scaled and running far away from license plate. I want to extract features from license plate only once and then extract features only from frame.
My logic is somewhere wrong. What could be a problem here?

Comment: This is not an answer but a question in turn. Can we use opticalflow tracking to track markers for this type of scenario also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200186/track-numbered-markers-in-a-video

Comment: Mat roi (mask, Rect(bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height)); - here: replace bb with squares[0]? I m just guessing, you didn't give the whole code, dunno what bb is and I m guessing what squares variable is...